# Tool to compare FTP repository

Tags: ftp, comparison

I would like to know if there is a (free) tool to compare local files with a distant repository. Something with a good gui would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the FTP directory as a Network Place, it can be treated as a local drive.

This means that any directory compare tool can be used, of which there are heaps.

If you need more info, alert me by adding a comment below.

Answer (score 2):

**[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com)** is not free but can be evaluated for some times.

You can compare local files with files stored on a FTP site. The "Synchronize Dirs" feature is great at that, comparing directories recursively. For files with differences, you can compare easily their content (if they're text-based).

As explained in [this review](http://www.wrotniak.net/topsoft/wcm.html):

> Another useful feature is
>   synchronization of the contents of two
>   directories (or directory trees). Try
>   it and you'll ever use the
>   brain-damaged Microsoft Briefcase
>   again. Even better: one of these
>   directories can be on the remote FTP
>   server; this is lifesaver for these of
>   us who keep developing their Web sites
>   on their PCs, and need to move the
>   updated files to the server, while
>   purging the "stale" ones from it.

[image]